# Gatling jbdc feeder error

Tags: gatling

I am able to insert the datas manually.

val testData2 = jdbcFeeder("jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.87.54.8:1521:wahipaD", "myHPHB_MI_SYSTS", "myHPHB_MI_SYST", """insert into TRN_USER_ACCOUNT(USER_ACCT_SID,LOGIN_ID,PWD,ACNT_TYPE_LKPCD,TENANT_CID,OPRTNL_FLAG,CREATED_BY,CREATED_DATE,MODIFIED_BY,MODIFIED_DATE) VALUES (2525,'user2','pwd','NORMAL',26,'A','1',sysdate,1026,sysdate)""")

As you said , first i need to export my excel sheet using csv file. I have done this. then how to read csv file and how to insert into db. I got struck with this. please help.
![enter image description here][1]
PFA

Thanks ,
Mohanpriya

Answer (score 0):

jdbcFeeder is for reading records from the database, not inserting.
This will never work.

Answer (score 0):

while simulating the recorded scala file, the datas should fetch from csv file and insert into db.

If we simulate 100 users,Will it create 100 records in the database in case registration populates the database data ?

Thanks,
Mohanapriya